# How do I use the The login_required decorator in my URL?

Tags: django, django-authentication

I want to check that the user is authorized for certain URLs. I'm using generic views.

[The docs here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/generic-views/?from=olddocs#create-update-delete-generic-views) say the login_required can be passed as an optional arguments but I'm not sure. Something like this maybe: `(r'^$', 'archive_index', link_info_dict, 'coltrane_link_archive_index', login_required=True,),`

I have this and I would like to be able to use the login_required decorator within the URL. Is it possible? How can I do it?

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

from coltrane.models import Link

link_info_dict = {
    'queryset': Link.live.all(),
    'date_field': 'pub_date',
}

urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.date_based',
    (r'^$', 'archive_index', link_info_dict, 'coltrane_link_archive_index'),

    (r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/$', 'archive_year', link_info_dict, 'coltrane_link_archive_year'),

    (r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/$', 'archive_month', link_info_dict, 'coltrane_link_archive_month'),

    (r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/(?P<day>\d{2})/$', 'archive_day', link_info_dict, 'coltrane_link_archive_day'),

    (r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'object_detail', link_info_dict, 'coltrane_link_detail'),
```

### )

---

For example how would I protect this page here(there's no view to add the login_Required decorator to)?

```
(r'^$', 'django.views.generic.simple.direct_to_template', {
        'template': 'home.html'
    }, ),
```

Comment: Link is now dead.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To use decorators in urls.py you need use real functions instead of their names:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
import django.views.generic.date_based as views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', login_required(views.archive_index), link_info_dict,
            'coltrane_link_archive_index'),
    ...
```

Answer (score 7):

In Django 1.11+, at least, you can do it directly as you want. For example:

```
# urls.py

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

urlpatterns = [
    # Home path
    path('', login_required(TemplateView.as_view(template_name='core/home.html')), name='home'),
    # Another paths
    # ...
]
```

In this case, each time you try to enter the homepage, you must be logged in, otherwise you will go to the login screen and then return to your homepage.

Answer (score 1):

you can use decorate_url

http://github.com/vorujack/decorate_url

```
pip install decorate_url
```

Comment: You should probably disclose that this is your own package.

Answer (score 0):

Those docs are for generic views, which work slightly differently than custom views. Normally `login_required` is used to decorate a view; if you want to use it within a urlconf then you'll need to write a lambda to wrap the view.

Comment: are you saying i can't protect those urls. i can't protect generic views?

Answer (score 0):

For Django v4.1.4,
In addition to @catavaran's answer, when you are using a Custom Login URL instead of django's default login, then you need to give the custom url to the login_url parameter.

## urls.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

urlpatterns = [
    path('', login_required(TemplateView.as_view(template_name='app_name/template_name.html'),login_url='/custom_login_url/'), name='path-name'),
]
```