# django redirect with login

Tags: django, session, authentication, hyperlink

I have trouble in the login process

```
def zero_default_auth(request):
    print 'default auth............'
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    message = ''

    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user, )
            print "login success"

            message="success!!!"
        else:
            message = 'disable'
    else:
        message = 'error!'

    return render(request, 'index_zero.html')
```

this is my login view.

The template nav bar is

```
<li><a href="{% url 'intershell:zero_index' %}">Link to the zero</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'intershell:zero_join' %}">JOIN page</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'intershell:ajax_test' %}">ajax page</a></li>
```

When the link is clicked, login data no longer exists.
How can I pass request session data to another page?

Comment: Which link is clicked? There are three links.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't understand very much under the hood of Django, but when you do the:

```
login(request, user)
```

Django saves the user’s ID in the session, using the session framework.

1. If you would like to know if the user is authenticated in the template, just 
   do this in your html file.

   ```
   {% if user.is_authenticated %}
       <!-- Show only to authenticated user -->
   {% endif %}
   ```

   That will only work if the 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth' in your settings.py file, otherwise the user variable won't be available in the template. The way the context is declared in Django 1.8 changed, so check documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#template-context-processors)
2. If you want to check on the View, use this:
   Source (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests)

   ```
   if request.user.is_authenticated():
       # logged user
   else:
       # not logged
   ```

   You can also check in View with decorators:
   Source (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator)

   ```
   from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

   @login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
   def my_view(request):
       ...
   ```
3. You can also check on the Url.py file, to do that check here: [How do I use the The login_required decorator in my URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722811/how-do-i-use-the-the-login-required-decorator-in-my-url)

Comment: i found the problem.... django baseURL and JQuery baseURL was different. anyway thank you for your help!